# Tell me please what nosql solution is best suited for use with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nosql

Tell me please what nosql solution (MongoDB, RavenDB, Cassandra, etc.) are best suited for use with ASP.NET MVC? and why(speed, ease of use, stability, etc.)?
and examples of its use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, for ASP.NET MVC it doesn't matter as it runs on .NET Framework, you should ask a solution for .NET

have a look [here](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/978742866/document-databases-compared-couchdb-mongodb-ravendb), i'd recommand RavenDB because it already has a .NET API included and it's written in C#